# Editar una linea con mat-table

Tags: angular

Estoy realizando una tabla con `mat-table` y la idea es mediante un botón poder realizar una edición de esa linea. El problema es que al realizar la edición se activan todas las celdas para ser editadas, y me gustaría reducirlo a solo en la que se ha realizado click. ¿Como puedo realizar esto?

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" width="100%" matSort id="myTable">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let objetos"> <span *ngIf="valor">{{objeto.nombre}} </span> 

    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" *ngIf="!valor">

       <mat-select placeholder="nombre"> 
        <mat-option *ngFor="let lista of listaNombre" [value]="lista">
          {{lista}} 
        </mat-option>       
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field> 
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="editar">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Editar </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let objetos2"> {{objetos2.editar}}
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="editar(objetos2)" *ngIf="valor">
        <mat-icon id="btnEdit">edit</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="save(objetos2)" *ngIf="!valor">
        <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Añado el controlador. Básicamente es una función que recibe los valores que hay en la fila. Me he dado cuenta que los valores son correctos y pertenecen a la fila a la que se realiza click. No se si el control de la edición se debería realizar desde esta función.

```
editar(fila) {
    this.gsaServices.getListaNombres().subscribe(result => {
      this.listaNombre= result;
      console.log ("resultado de listaNombre:" , this.listaNombre);
    },

      error => {
               console.log(
          'Error, Se ha producido un error al recibir lista Nombres  '
        );
      }
    );

     this.valor = false;
    console.log("Se hizo click en editar", fila);
    this.createDataSource();
  }
```

Comment: Deberías añadir el código del controlador, ese método editar parece ser clave en el comportamiento

Comment: Por otro lado, he encontrado [esto](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5u7cy?file=app%2Ftable-editing-example.html), lo mismo te es útil

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, aunque no me sirve porque la edición es igual que en mi ejemplo, se editan todas a la vez, y la idea es que solo sea la linea seleccionada.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución sería asignar una propiedad "virtual" a cada dato de los resultados y así brindarle a cada uno su propio estado "editable"

```
this.gsaServices.getListaNombres().subscribe((result: any[]) => {
    this.listaNombre = result.map(r => {
        r['editable'] = false;
        return r;
    });
})
```

En el html, utilizas `objeto.editable` como flag para activar/desactivar la edición de "objeto", el click haría algo como: `(click)="objeto.editable = !objeto.editable"` para "alternar" entre edición activa e inactiva...

Comment: No me funciona, me da error el código que has puesto y aun así se siguen viendo todos editable. Gracias de todas formas por la ayuda. Lo ideal sería poder encontrar algún enlace que realice exactamente esto.

Comment: 1. En dónde te da error?
2. Cual es el error?
3. Ten en cuenta que debes adaptar la solución a como tienes estructurado tu código. Por ejemplo: puede que `result` sea un objeto y no un `array` como estoy asumiendo yo en la respuesta. Quizá sea algo distinto en `this.createDataSource();`